# adding ec2 instance to wombat oam monitoring tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang, oam

I am trying to add erlang nodes running in amazon EC2 to wombat oam which is again running in EC2. When i am trying to add local nodes and other nodes not running in EC2 i am able to add it to wombat. but when i am trying to add any EC2 node it gives following errors

```
***node is not discoverable and some tNode riak@1**.**.**.**1 should be reachable.
Hints:
The Erlang node may have a different cookie from the one specified.
The Erlang node may have been registered addressing the host in a different way than specified.***
```

I tried telnet and they are able to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
epmd -names
```

This will give you nodes that the Erlang VM knows about. `epmd` is a daemon that runs in the background and keeps the nodes connected. It runs on a separate port `4369` and each VM has an additional port opened per node that it communicates with, e.g.:

```
g@someserv1:~ % epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name hbd at port 22200
```

You would need to ensure that first of all the 4369 port is opened, e.g. that you can telnet to that port from the other box. Then you can try to ping that machine with `net_adm:ping/1`, e.g.:

```
(hbd@someserv1.somehost.com)17> net_adm:ping('hbd@someserv2.somehost.com').
pong
```

Of course both machines would need to use the same cookie to communicate with each other.

On the other hand Wombat uses a specific port to communicate with the monitored instances, so please also check if that port is opened by telneting to it.