# Erlang - Nodes don't recognize

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing

I'm trying to use distributing programming in Erlang.

But I had a problem, I can't communicate two Erlang's nodes to communicate.

I tried to put the same atom in the "Magical cookies", but it didn't work.

I tried to use command net:ping(node), but reponse was pang (didn't reconigze another node), or used nodes(), to see if my first node see the second node, but it didn't work again.

The first and second node is CentOS in VMWare, using bridge connection in network adaptor.

I entered command ping outside Erlang between VM's and they reconigze each one.

I start the first node, but the second node open process, but can't find the node pong.

```
(pong@localhost)8> tut17:start_pong().
true


(ping@localhost)5> c(tut17).
{ok,tut17}
(ping@localhost)6> tut17:start_ping(pong@localhost).
<0.55.0>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to provide some code and context for what you did to get some help.

Comment: did you check the firewall configuration and the router if any?

Comment: can you post `epdm -names` from both nodes?

Comment: Host 1 `epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name ping at port 33880`  Host 2 `epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name pong at port 59495`

Comment: And what does `node().` return from the Erlang shell on both nodes?

Comment: One more way is to kill epmd on both nodes and start it in debug mode, e.g.: `epmd -d`. It will then print debug messages when you try to ping the other node.

Comment: Host 1 `ping@host1` Host 2 `pong@host2`. I'm using command `erl -sname` to give name to nodes. I will try kill them and start debug.

Comment: I tested again, I forget to put the same atom in cookie. It WORKS. Thank you, everybody. Mainly, Amiramax being patient.

Comment: Good job and you are welcome, I hope you will persist with learning Erlang :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713136/adding-ec2-instance-to-wombat-oam-monitoring-tool/35721987#35721987).

The distribution is provided by a daemon called [Erlang Port Mapper Daemon](http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html). By default it listens on port 4369 so you need to make sure that that port is opened between the nodes. Additionally, each started Erlang VM opens an additional port to communicate with other VMs. You can see those ports with `epmd -names`:

```
g@someserv1:~ % epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name hbd at port 22200
```

You can check if the port is opened by doing `telnet` to it, e.g.:

```
g@someserv1:~ % telnet 127.0.0.1 22200
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

You can change the port to the port you want to check, e.g. 4369, and also the IP to the desired IP. Doing `ping` is not enough because it uses its own [ICMP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) which is different that TCP used by the Erlang distribution to communicate, e.g. ICMP may be allowed but TCP may be blocked.

**Edit:**

Please follow this guide [Distributed Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) to start an Erlang VM in distributed mode. Then you can use `net_adm:ping/1` to connect to it from another node, e.g.:

```
(hbd@someserv1.somehost.com)17> net_adm:ping('hbd@someserv2.somehost.com').
pong
```

Only then `epmd -names` will show the started Erlang VM on the list.

**Edit2:**

Assume that there are tho hosts, A and B. Each one runs one Erlang VM. `epmd -names` run on each host shows for example:

Host A:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name servA at port 22200
```

Host B:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name servB at port 22300
```

You need to be able to do:

On Host A:

```
telnet HostB 4369
telent HostB 22300
```

On Host B:

```
telnet HostA 4369
telnet HostA 22200
```

where HostA and HostB are those hosts' IP addresses (.e.g HostA is IP of Host A, HostB is IP of Host B).

If the telnet works correctly then you should be able to do `net_adm:ping/1` from one host to the other, e.g. on Host A you would ping the name of Host B. The name is what the command `node().` returns.

Comment: I edited the answer to add info how to start the VM node properly. `epmd -names` doesn't show the VM unless it knows about it, e.g. the VM is started and can be connected to. Please read the guide to learn how the distribution work, in short, the Erlang VM tries to communicate with `epmd` to register in it and to discover other nodes. Then it creates a new port for each VM that it could successfully connect to through `epmd`.

Comment: Yes, I followed this guide before, but it didn't work.  `[erlang@localhost ~]$ epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:`  I have only one port 4369.  I set my cookie to the same atom, but my nodes don't connect.

Comment: You can't have more than one port 4369. `epmd` is running on 4369 and each newly started VM will have its own port. How did you start your VM and parameters did you use when starting your VM? What do you get when you do `node().` in the Erlang shell?

Comment: Sorry, Amiramix. I tried at the same host and it works, but for different hosts (Like 2 CentOS in VMWare). I think I have to do something different. Thank you for help me!

Comment: One step at a time. You need to establish if epmd can communicate between those hosts. You need to 1. Establish on which port each Erlang VM listens for connections from other Erlang VMs using the command `epmd -names`. 2. Establish if you can telnet to that port from the other host. I will add an edit to show you what I mean.

Comment: Amiramix, I did it. Telnet is working for both hosts!

Comment: You mean telnet from Host 1 to Host 2 port 59495 works (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have a node name for your nodes, or they won't be available to connect with. E.g.:

```
erl -sname somenode@node1
```

If you're using separate hosts, then you need to make sure that the node names are resolvable to ip addresses somehow. An easy to way to do this is using /etc/hosts.

```
# Append a similar line to the /etc/hosts file
10.10.10.10 node1
```

For more helpful answers, you should post what you see in your terminal when you try this.

---

**EDIT**

It looks like your shell is auto picking "localhost" as the node name. You can't send messages to another host with the address "localhost". When specifying the name on the shell, try using the @ syntax to specify the node name as well:

```
# On host 1:
erl -sname ping@host1

# On host 2
erl -sname pong@host2
```

Then edit the host file so host1 and host2 will resolve to the right IP.

Comment: I edited my question, that I'm trying use tutorial ping pong from Erlang quickstart. Node pong start successfully, but node ping can't communicate with Pong node.