# Newly added global gen server can receive cast messages from vnode but not from riak_client in Riak_Kv

Tags: erlang, riak

I added a new global gen server to riak_kv, which works as a sequencer. I need to send a cast message to this gen server from both vnode and riak_client (before spawning the fsm in riak client).When I start the gen server, the cast message from vnode to gen server works fine. But the cast message from riak_client to gen server throws a noproc error (An error which can be thrown when the gen server is not running). The method I called in gen_server is the same. The cookie is also the same. The way I run the new gen_server is running bin/riak attach and then running the gen server. Actually gen server is running but riak_client does not see it as running. Can you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check if the nodes can communicate e.g. as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762894/erlang-nodes-dont-recognize/35769392#35769392 Also, it may happen that the Riak node changes the cookie when it's running.

Comment: What exactly is the function call you are using to send the cast?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. The problem happens when I invoke test method in the riak_client module. It does not happen when I invoke the operations via bashobench_RiakClient. As I'm using basho_bench for my experiments, the problem is solved.

Comment: After adding the below 2 lines just before calling the gen_server in the test method of the riak module, the test method also worked fine.            Status=net_kernel:connect_node('riak@127.0.0.1'),%name of the global gen_ser
 global:sync(),         but not sure how it fixed the problem.